# c# HttpWebRequest Error: 503 server unavailable Fiddler

Tags: c#

Я отправляю с помощью HttpWebRequest, Post запрос на сайт(не имеет значение какой).
В ответ получаю ошибку **503 server unavailable**.
Но стоит мне только запустить Fiddler, то сразу все начинает работает, запрос обрабатывается, сервер возвращает информацию.
Кто то в курсе, почему так и что делать?

Ответ получен, тема решена. Спасибо @Digital Core

Comment: А теперь почитайте все это и поставьте себя на наше место. Представьте что вы совершенно нечего не знаете о сервере, об использованном коде, об отправляемом запросе, вы даже не знаете POST он или GET, а может PUT? Представили? А теперь попробуйте ответить... Как успехи?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, не имеет значение. Любой запрос

Comment: Ну как не имеет значение, сайт может требовать только определенный агент, или какую нибудь куку, может в заголовке что уникальное просит. Как мы вам должны помочь? Все это индивидуально! Устанавливайте User-Agent браузера, если не поможет - отлавливайте запрос отправленный через браузер и через программу и ищите отличия.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, это понятно, но что делает фидлер с моим запросом, что сервер вдруг начинает работать?

Comment: Он обычно не меняет запросы, чисто их ловит. Так что я лично без понятия.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ? вот вот, я сам лично очень удивлен

Answer (score 1):

Если на сервере нет ограничений по UserAgent, IP, Cookie, данный метод точно будет работать. И конечно если это не клоака, где учитывается откуда вы пришли, и с каким запросом.

```
    public string DownloadString(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "text/html";
        request.Referer = $"{url}";
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36";
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
        string WorkingPage = strReader.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();
        return WorkingPage;
    }
```

Comment: спасибо, чудесным образом помогло